# Why does my program translate all of my vertices?

Tags: opengl

I have two classes with their own model coordinates, colors, etc. I also have two shader programs that are logically the same. First I execute one shader program, edit the uniforms with the traditional view and projection matrices, and then I call the class to edit the model matrix uniquely, and then draw it's  primitives. Immediately afterwards, I do the exact same thing, but with the second shader program, edit the uniforms again, and call the second class to draw it's primitives and it's own unique model matrix coordinates. 
In the second class, I translate the model matrix each iteration, but not in the first class. For some reason it translates the model matrix in the first class as well, and I dont know why?

Source code:

```
//First shader program, update view and proj matrix, and have first class draw it's vertices
executable.Execute();
GLuint viewMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(executable.getComp(), "viewMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(freeView.getFreeView()));
GLuint projMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(executable.getComp(), "projectionMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix.getProjectionMatrix()));
temp.useClass(executable);

//Second Shader program, update view and proj matrix, and have second class draw it's vertices
executable2.Execute();
viewMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(executable2.getComp(), "viewMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(freeView.getFreeView()));
projMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(executable2.getComp(), "projectionMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix.getProjectionMatrix()));
temp2.useClass(executable2);
```

VertexShader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 positions;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 colors;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(positions, 1.0f);
    color = colors;
}
```

The second vertex shader is logically the same, with just different variable names, and the fragment shader just outputs color.

useClass function (from class one):

```
glBindVertexArray(tempVAO);
glm::mat4 modelMat;
modelMat = glm::mat4();
GLuint modelMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(exe.getComp(), "modelMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMat));
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

useClass function (from class two):

```
glBindVertexArray(tempVAO);
for(GLuint i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    model[i] = glm::translate(model[i], gravity);
    GLuint modelMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(exe.getComp(), "modelMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model[i]));
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
}
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Both classes have data protection, and I just don't understand how translating the model matrix in one class, makes the model matrix in another class get translated as well, when using two shader programs? When I use one shader program for both classes, the translating works out fine, but not so much when I use two shader programs(one for each class)...

EDIT: After working on my project a little more, I figure out that the same problem happens when I compile and link two different shader programs with the same exact vertex and fragment shader, and just use each shader program before I draw from each class. So now the question I have is more along the lines of: Why does using two identical shader programs in between draws cause all of the vertices/model matrices to get translated?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Perhaps in the code you don show... Are you sure you use different shaders? Do you use `glUseProgram` with the proper id for each class?

Comment: Yes, I pass a reference of each shader program instance to it's unique class, and from their the class just edits the model matrix and then draws the primitives. When I use one of the shader programs, it works out fine, when I use the same shader program twice, things work out fine, but when I use two different shader programs(even though they are logically the same), everything gets translated...

Comment: Where do you `glUseProgram`? The uniform location can be retrieved at any time by `glGetUniformLocation`, and stored for later use, after the program is linked successfully (`glLinkProgram`), but to set the value of a uniform variable, the program has to be the active program. This means `glUseProgram` has to be done before `glUniformMatrix4fv`.

Comment: When I call `executable.Execute()`, `glUseProgram()` gets called. Same for the second shader program. I do only call `glUniformMatrix4fv`, when I have a shader program active...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. Basically, since there is not really a way to directly exit the execution of a shader, my program was getting confused when I passed shaders getting executed through functions into other parts of the program. For some reason the program was thinking two shader programs were getting executed at the same time, hence why the model matrix was not getting reset consistently. To fix this issue, I limited the scope of each individual shader. Instead of having shaders executed in the same function and then passed through to other classes, I put each shader in the respective class that it gets used in.